# Is the 6-month expiry rule for passports applicable also for visas?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, visa-expiration

I'm aware about the rule that you can't enter a country if your passport is going to expire in 6 months or less.

Does this apply also for visas? Let's say that my US visa expires in July 2023. Does it mean that I can't enter in the first semester of 2023?

Comment: "I'm aware about the rule that you can't enter a country if your passport is going to expire in 6 months or less." It depends on the country you are entering, the country of your passport, the status you are entering on, etc. There is no universal rule.

Comment: I know that is not universal, but is very common

Comment: "6 months" is a very common period in visa validities, that would make all of them invalid the day they were issued.

Answer (score 15):

You can enter the US until the last day of the validity of the visa. The visa is only used for entry, once you're admitted what matters is your status and it's duration, which would be listed on the stamp in your passport and the [electronic I-94](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home).

*Note: This applicable only for US Visa. Many other countries have rules like visa needs to be valid for entire duration. But none have 6 month rule.*